# How can I stream all audio from my Mac to my Android phone?

Tags: audio, streaming

I'm sick of switching my headphone jack from my Mac to phone and vice versa. Is there any way to stream all audio playing on my Mac to my Android phone, so I can hear any audio from either my Mac or my phone through the same pair of headphones, at the same time?

Comment: Huh?  *Stream all the audio being broadcast...* Broadcasting *is* streaming...  This question is completely unclear and not only missing substantial details, but I also don't see how it's so difficult to unplug and replug a headphone jack.

Comment: @Allan Sorry, I updated the question. Hopefully that's more clear.

Comment: If your Mac and phone are on the same wifi network, this question suggests an app called AirDroid: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227428/mirror-mac-sound-on-android-phone?rq=1.

Comment: @nekomatic The question wasn't answered. I beleive he was saying it's technically possible, as AirDroid allows setting up a WiFi hotspot between Mac and Android, but not audio.

Comment: The question is still unclear - do you want to stream just music or *all* sounds including system sounds?  Am I understanding that you want sounds from the Mac and the Android phone to be present on a single set of *wired* headsets?  If this is the case, I don't see why a [Y Audio Cable Splitter](https://goo.gl/gLrwqQ) can't solve this issue for you.  Sometimes, the simplest solution is the best.

Comment: @Allan a Y cable is for connecting two devices (e.g. two pairs of headphones) to one output, not vice versa.

Comment: @Allan Yes, I want to stream all audio, including system sounds, that's why I said "all audio". That splitter looks like it would do that job, but I'll consider it a last resort. It would be nice if I could find a software solution.

Comment: @nekomatic Check the link. It's the opposite of what you're thinking.

Comment: @SillyGoose no, it's not. A cable will not 'merge' two audio outputs. Connecting one headset to two devices using this cable will probably not give good sound output and may damage one or both device outputs as it effectively shorts out the one that is attempting to produce a signal.

Comment: @nekomatic - actually it will.  These cables are not uni-directional. I am not advocating for it, but *it will work.*

Comment: @Allan **no.** Unless the cable contains a mixer and audio amplifier - which it clearly doesn't - then all it can possibly do is to short the outputs of the two devices together. If this appears to work for you then you've been lucky so far, but in general this risks drawing more current than a headphone output is designed for and ultimately damaging it. Don't do this.

Answer (score 3):

Rogue Amoeba's [**Airfoil**](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) will do what you want. Run Airfoil on your Mac and the **Airfoil Speakers** app on your Android device.

Alternatively, there may be free solutions. The protocol used by Apple devices to send audio to e.g. AppleTV and Airport Express devices is called **Airplay** and has been reverse-engineered by projects such as Shairport. There may be an Android app which emulates this protocol to make your phone into an Airplay destination. However you'll have to search carefully as the more common implementation is to enable the Android device to *send* audio to the AppleTV etc.

Answer (score 2):

I share my music from Mac with ArkMS http://arkmc.com/mac-osx-media-streaming-server-upnp-dlna/! Simply select folders with mp3 files and listen them on iPhone/Android in 8Player or ArkMS apps or Sonos speaker. It doesn't provide sound mirroring, music streaming only. Hope that helps.